# In metro, get all inherited classes of an (abstract) class?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I got stuck when trying to get all inherited classes in metro. The WinRT API is different from .net framework, so both the solutions ([solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944605/1613961) and [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665127/1613961)) don't work.

Any code or tool solution is appreciated.

I'm still trying. I will put my solution here if success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (based on the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944605/197913)):

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableOfType<T>(params object[] constructorArgs) where T : class, IComparable<T>
{
    List<T> objects = new List<T>();
    foreach (Type type in typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.ExportedTypes
                                   .Where(myType => myType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass && 
                                                    !myType.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract && 
                                                    myType.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
    {
        objects.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs));
    }
    objects.Sort();
    return objects;
}
```

Basically `TypeInfo` is now the main class for doing any reflection operations and you can get it by calling `GetTypeInfo()` on the `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Damir Arh.
Your solution is great although it only needs little modification.

One thing I observed is your static method can't be put into MainPage class, or compile-error would happen. Possibly it's because the initializing xaml conflicts with it.

On the other hand, I altered the original code to simpler and useful one with much less run-time error (The line in `objects.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs));` often leads to run-time error in many cases.). The main purpose is just to get all inherited classes after all.

```
    // GetTypeInfo() returns TypeInfo which comes from the namespace
    using System.Reflection;

    public List<Type> GetEnumerableOfType<T>(params object[] constructorArgs) where T : class
    {
        List<Type> objects = new List<Type>();

        IEnumerable<Type> s = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.ExportedTypes.Where(myType => myType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass &&
                                                         !myType.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract &&
                                                         myType.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));

        foreach (Type type in s)
            objects.Add(type);

        return objects;
    }
```

And the following is a test sample.

```
     var list = GetEnumerableOfType<UIElement>();

     foreach (var v in list)
         Debug.WriteLine(v.Name);
```